# Image loaded in ImageView is hiding the button

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, imageview

When I am loading an image(more specifically, an image of portrait shape) in an `ImageView` that image is sometimes covering the `Button` which is above the `ImageView`. The `ImageView` has `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`. My requirement is that the `ImageView` will wrap content but, won't cover up the button. I don't want to hardcode pixel values.

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context="mg.colorfilters.ResultActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/string3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:onClick="loadImageWithFilterOrSaveImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/string4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"` in the `Button`

Comment: Is there any way to mention how many pixels above?

Comment: You shouldn't use pixels use `dp` instead.

Comment: @Apoorv I use dp. You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Use `android:layout_marginBottom=""` to give margin below `Button`

Comment: Just tested, didn't solve the problem. Loaded image is still covering the button.

Answer (score 1):

You want your image to be at centre?

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

If yes, then may want to put your Button code below ImageView code, like

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/string4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:text="@string/string3"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:onClick="loadImageWithFilterOrSaveImage" />
```

This way the button will always be on top. If image is large, button will be visible on top of it. Use this solution only if you are OK with this behavior.

Comment: Yes, I want the image at the center. Your solution is very close to the solution I want, but not the exact solution.

Comment: You want image to be at center of screen and want button to be at center horizontal and top aligned. What happens when image dimensions grow? something will have to give way or you have to set max dimentions to image view

Comment: We can resize the ImageView maintaining the aspect ratio of the loaded image.

Comment: yup we can. I think setting max dimension should take care of aspect ratio. (if you do this remember to do dp-px calculation, as u'll need dimension in dp but it is set in px)

Comment: I've already found that out. Using android:maxHeight="300dp" and android:adjustViewBounds="true". Any way to mention relative dimensions inside RelativeLayout. I am getting warnings if I use layout_weight.

Comment: What exactly you mean by relative dimensions? We have layout_alignLeft="viewId", layout_toRightOf="viewId", layout_above="viewId" etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Layout.xml 
please insert `android:layout_above="@+id/button1` line in `<ImageView>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a scrollview inside the relative layout and use a linear layout in vertical orientation in the scrollview...then add your button and imageview in the linear layout.....I havent tried this but i think this will work :D